# How to customize Header in android

Tags: android

I want to show following image in my activity header:

[image]
The image is only the black part. The right part should be the header background. And the divider between header and body should be removed.

How can I achieve that?

The total change I need:

```
1. Remove the divider between header and body
2. Change the background color of header to blue
3. Set an background image on the left side of the header
```

Comment: Are you trying to style the ActionBar this way? If so, do you need the actionbar functionality? If not, it would be easier to just use a custom layout. Don't worry about "changing" it, just come up with a layout you like and remove the actionbar altogether.

Comment: I thought of using `actionBarSherlock` so that I can achieve these easily. Should I use actionBarSherlock or not to override the layout?

Comment: It depends. Are you going to be using it as an ActionBar, or not? Meaning, do you need it to have a menu, home button, etc? If not, you can just use a custom layout as a fragment, and place it at the top of each of your activities.

Comment: I don't need any menu or anything of actionBar and I have only one activity. So should I use a fragment? I think `Fragement` and `actionBar` both are unnecessary. So what can I use?

Comment: If it's just one activity, you're right, both are unnecessary. Just use a basic LinearLayout with the images/text you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use any option menu or any other actionBarSherlock functionality, then there is no need to this library. You can use any theme with *`NoTitleBar`* and create a custom `RelativeLayout` t create the header.

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
 <!--Anything -->
</style>
```

**Your layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#6ccff6">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abs_bg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="July 25"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Put any other layout/view here -->

</LinearLayout>
```